# AutoHotKey for holding down C key and relese it in game

Tags: autohotkey

Hi I'm in a game that I can't crotch without having to hold down <kbd>C</kbd> key.

I just want to know if there is a script that allows you to do it like if I hold down <kbd>C</kbd> key for sec it keeps holding it until I use <kbd>C</kbd> key again to release it.

I try a lot of combination, but as soon as I start the script  it's just spam <kbd>C</kbd> key and stop after the loop number I gave it which is not what I want.

If its not possible to do it like that I would go like this if I push <kbd>C</kbd> and up arrow key it holds <kbd>C</kbd> until I push <kbd>C</kbd> and down arrow.

Can anyone please give me the script?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your post is almost impossible to read. Please divide it into paragraphs, as at the moment it's one long sentence. Add also your attempted script so we can see what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you can stand to have toggle keys other than <kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>▲</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>▼</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, then the following `.ahk` script might work for you:

*ex. Using <kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>F2</kbd> to toggle <kbd>C</kbd> (Crouch):*

```
F1::
    Loop
    {
        If GetKeyState("F2" , "P")
            Break
        Send c
        Sleep 100
    }
Return
```

---

*Note that `Sleep` A) isn't required and B) will necessitate <kbd>F2</kbd> to be held longer to break the loop at higher values (e.g. `Sleep 1000`).*

---

Answer (score 0):

This script get the job done for one key, it work for m.

```
#Persistent
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2
toggle := False

z UP::
toggle := !toggle

Loop {
    If (!toggle) {
    send,{z UP}
        break
    }
    send,{z DOWN}
sleep 10
}
Return
```